# what are *.r files in C?

Tags: c, class-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is a “private header” in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958671/what-is-a-private-header-in-c)

I refer to this question:

[Can you write object-oriented code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c)

The accepted answer to that question posted a link to a book: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf

In this book, the author uses *.r files, in addition to *.c and *.h files. The *.r files are used like-headers, hiding the implementation of "C-classes" from users

My question is what are *.r files?

are they something standard for coding in C?

Or is it something that Axel Schreiner came up with when writing his book?

Comment: That's definitely not a normal C file extension.

Comment: This might answer it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958671/what-is-a-private-header-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick look at the PDF, and here is an example of what you're referring to:

> The type description struct Class in
>   new.r should correspond to the method
>   declarations in new.h:

---

```
struct Class {
  size_t size;
  void * (* ctor) (void * self, va_list * app);
  void * (* dtor) (void * self);
  void (* draw) (const void * self);
};
```

`.r` is referring to the representation (hence the `.r`) of the so-called class, where the header file actually defines the more friendly looking method names:

```
void * new (const void * class, ...);
void delete (void * item);
void draw (const void * self);
```

And finally the c source file contains the actual function code:

```
void draw (const void * self)
{ 
  const struct Class * const * cp = self;
  assert(self && * cp && (* cp) —> draw);
  (* cp) —> draw(self);
}
```

Long story short, yes the `.r` was something that Axel Schreiner came up with in his book, and as mentioned the r in `.r` is "representation".

Answer (score 3):

He calls them **r**epresentation files and hence the `.r` extension. It could might as well be `.p` or `.q`. Its just a personal convention used by the author.